# Rails 4 not loading css.scss files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a Rails 4 app that was loading the css.scss files just fine. Then I did something to break it, I don't know what, and reverting to the last git check-in isn't fixing the problem.

My structure is exactly as `rails new [project name]` left it, and I've never had to look at how the assets get loaded. Reading up on the asset pipeline just left me more confused.

I'm actually putting all of my styling in `app\assets\stylesheets\application.css.scss`, which begins with

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

as I believe it should, but (judging from the Chrome developer tools view) the application isn't even getting as far as loading that. So where does a Rails 4 application get told to load `app\assets\stylesheets\application.css.scss`?

(Yes, I see others have problems with loading the stylesheets, but the advice always seems to be to put the stylesheets where I already have them or to include those lines in the application stylesheet that I already have, so it looks as if my problem is something else).

Comment: Keep travelling backwards to find the bad commit? (see git bisect for a good way of doing this)

Comment: It was working fine at the last commit, which makes me think that the problem is with a file that wasn't in the last commit -- either an excluded file or a new one. But I'd like some idea where to look. And even more, I'd like to understand the asset pipeline: tracking this down (even if I do need help) could be a good step towards that.

Comment: I can't answer your question exactly, but if you need more help understanding the asset pipeline, take a look at the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) that covers it. Helped me out when I started with asset stuff.

Comment: I have problems watching videos at work, so it looks as if I'll have to check that out at home :(

Comment: Ok, the video shows me how to check all the right things are in the pipeline, and `app\assets` is in the pipeline just as it should be. So what might be the next reason for it not loading what's in there?

Comment: have you solved your problem yet? I seem to have a similar problem

Comment: I was early enough in the project that I just scrapped the whole thing and started again, and that time the CSS worked just fine. So Yes, I solved it, but not in a way that's likely to be of any use to anyone else. Sorry. :(